How to randomize displace modifier pattern?
Is there any way to randomize pattern of displace modifier?
Sometimes stones in texture look bad, I want to generate it again. Resizing texture won't solve this problem. Maybe there is a way to change the grid settings or add a parameter to the custom settings?


Can we have a screenshot of your node tree?
